# Program output appears only sometimes in multi-threaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread, cout

I'm using boost threads to parallelize the calculations in my program. A controller object manages the calculation jobs and the results. I create a bunch of worker threads which get their jobs from the controller object while the main thread displays the results. The results need to be shown in the correct order. To achieve this I use boost futures in a `std::deque`. `GetNewJob()` adds a new `boost::promise` to the end of the deque and returns a pointer. `GetNextResult()` takes a result from the front end of the queue. If no result is ready yet, it blocks the calling thread.

The important parts of my Controller class:

```
class Controller
{
public:
    Controller();
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<Results> > GetNewJob();
    Results GetNextResult();

    class NoJobsLeft{};
    class NoResultsLeft{};

private:
    bool JobsLeft() const;
    bool ResultsLeft() const;

    std::deque<boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<Results> > > queue_;
    boost::mutex mutex_;
    boost::condition_variable condition_;
};
```

Worker function:

```
void DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<Results> >
                    promise(controller.GetNewJob());

            //do calculations

            promise->set_value(results);
        }
    }
    catch(NoJobsLeft)
    {
    }
}
```

Main program code:

```
Controller controller(args);

boost::thread_group worker_threads;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < n_cpus; ++i)
    worker_threads.create_thread(DoWork);

try
{
    while(true)
    {
        Results results = controller.GetNextResult();

        std::cout << results;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
catch(NoResultsLeft)
{
}

worker_threads.join_all();
```

Sometimes this works just fine, all results are displayed. **But very often I cannot see any output at all.**

I do not use `cout` in the worker threads.

---

Implementations of `GetNewJob()`, `GetNextResult()`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<Results> > Controller::GetNewJob()
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);

    if (!JobsLeft())
        throw NoJobsLeft();

    //determine more information about the job, not important here

    queue_.push_back(boost::make_shared<boost::promise<Results> >());

    condition_.notify_one();

    return queue_.back();
}


Results Controller::GetNextResult()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::promise<Results> > results;
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);

        if (!ResultsLeft())
            throw NoResultsLeft();

        while(!queue_.size())
        {
            condition_.wait(lock);
        }

        results = queue_.front();
        queue_.pop_front();
    }

    return results->get_future().get();
}

bool Controller::ResultsLeft() const
{
    return (queue_.size() || JobsLeft()) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: @Fredrik: `std::endl` flushes the stream implicitely.

Comment: Then I learnt something new today! thanx

Comment: Can you please show us implementations of `GetNewJob()` and `GetNextResult()` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where you don't see any output it could be throwing `NoResultsLeft` because nothing is in the queue on the first pass.  The other possibility is that it is failing to add things to the queue in the first place or throwing `NoJobsLeft`.  Adding `std::cout` statements into your catch blocks might help identify what's going on.

However if the results can't be displayed asynchronously then there is no reason for the mechanism you might as well wait all.  There is no guarantee of the order of completion of threads only the order in which you add the results to the queue via `boost::promise` so you have to block anyway in `GetNextResult` at least until the first thread completes.

If you want to display results sequentially your controller could gather all results in the same way and fire a `boost::function` to display the results in the correct order when everything is ready.

**Edit:**

BTW `while(!queue_.size())` really ought to be `while(queue_.empty())` while technically anything non-zero is interpreted as true methods named `size()`, `length()`, etc really look ugly when used as an if condition. Same goes for `return (queue_.size() || JobsLeft()) ? true : false;` which could be `return (!queue.empty() || JobsLeft());`

Comment: Thanks, you had the right idea with `NoResultsLeft`. It was thrown right in the beginning because of a mistake I made when initializing a variable which is used in `JobsLeft()`. This lead to `JobsLeft()` returning `false` in the beginning. But now I came across a deadlock once which doesn't seem to be reproducable. I'll let the program run in a loop over night to see if it occurs agein. Also thanks for the other tips, especially with the ternary operator. I wonder why I didn't see this :)

Comment: I do not quite understand your second paragraph. Could you please explain this again in other words?

Comment: The gist was since you want to display the results in the order they were launched not the order they were completed you could make things a lot easier for yourself by waiting for all threads to complete and then only processing results and displaying them afterward.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this. But if I implemented it like that and I wanted to perform a LARGE number of calculations, I might run out of memory. So I decided to put it to stdout directly, from where it can be redirected to a file.

Comment: Well you need enough memory to perform all calculations anyway as all threads are staying in scope until you reach the `join_all` call *after* the `cout` and it looks like you're only spawning as many threads as CPUs initially so short of a runaway memory leak in your calculation I doubt that would be an issue. It was just a suggestion for simplicity though.